# He sent me a file of (a) very large size

Tags: articles

I was told that both are correct.

> He sent me a file of **a** very large size
>
> He sent me a file of very large size

How is that possible?

Comment: This question is just asking for a mention of [*rodents of unusual size*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nv9CkjkOyzo) from *The Princess Bride.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you said "*a very large file*", you would easily recognise that "very large" is an adjective phrase, right?

The word 'size' is a noun. Like the words 'kind' or 'type' it is used to denote a category or group to which something belongs. But nouns can be used as adjectives, and adjectives can be used as nouns.

When you say "*files of a large size*" you are not describing the file as being 'very large' - you are assigning it to a category of "very large size".

This can work with or without an article, and can vary depending on the specificity of the noun or in some cases just what has become most idiomatic.

- Person of colour (no article)
- Two of a kind (indefinite article)
- Close encounters of the third kind (definite article)

With your example, any could work, depending on the context.